# How can I share String messages with multiple producers and a single receiver in Rust (crossbeam)?

Tags: string, multithreading, rust, channel

I have a project where multiple threads will transmit readings in String format, and I want them to be consumed by one handler thread.

Unfortunately, Strings don't implement Copy/Clone so I can't pass references of my crossbeam channel so a second thread without getting the error

```
--> src/main.rs:71:30
|
61 |     let (tx_ws, rx_ws) = unbounded();
|          --------- move occurs because `tx_ws` has type `crossbeam::Sender<node::WebsocketResponse>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
70 |     let node0_thread = thread::spawn(move || node0::run(Some(&n0_settings), tx_ws.clone()));
|                             ------- value moved into closure here                   --------- variable moved due to use in closure
71 |     let node1_thread = thread::spawn(move || node1::run(Some(&n1_settings), tx_ws.clone()));
|                              ^^^^^^^ value used here after move                  --------- use occurs due to use in closure
```

What tricks do you guys have to get around this? I understand String is a non-boxed type, but not sure how to get around it.

Is there another way to send String like messages over a crossbeam-channel?

Comment: String does implement `Clone` btw. Please add code a [mcve] next time and make sure to copy&paste the error message, because it is now not formatted and all the crucial error information are gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `move` closures, which try to move any captured variables in, and you're doing it twice on the same variable (`tx_ws`) into different closures.

If `Sender` were `Copy`, this would be fine and it would get automatically copied, but because it's only `Clone`, you need to explicitly clone it. You're trying to call `clone()`, but inside the closure (so *after* the move happens), which is too late.

After line 61, add a line like:
`let tx_ws_clone = tx_ws.clone();`
and change one of the closures to use `tx_ws_clone` rather than `tx_ws`, and things should start working. Inside the closures you don't need to clone `tx_ws`; you only need to clone it *before* it gets moved :)